# Cannot install Phalanger 4.0

Tags: php, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, phalanger

I was already using Phalanger 3.0 via command line. I want to update version and also use in Visual Studio, now I'm trying to install version 4.0.

I have `VS Express 2013 for Desktop`, However...

[image]

Cannot choose any items... Isn't it suported with this edition?

[image]

Command line tool that existed in version 3.0 has gone in version 4.0...

[image]

So, the question is

1. **How can I install Phalanger 4.0 in Visual Studio?**
2. **How can I use Phalanger 4.0 via command line?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio Express is not extensible. You can use free VS Community instead or any other but Express.

As I know there is no installer containing phpc.exe since the installer is only intented for VS IDE. You can however compile Phalanger from sources to get phpc.exe.